# Prove tail deviation implies bounded mean

Tags: probability

Prove that if $$P(X\ge\epsilon)\le e^{-2m\epsilon^2}$$ then $$E(e^{2(m-1)X^2})\le m$$

I could use the first implies bounded higher-order moments then implies bounded Taylor expansion. But is there an easier way?

Comment: Are you talking about non-negative RVs, $X \ge 0$?

Comment: No...............